# modulo operation with negative numbers in python

Tags: python, modulo

I found this definition for modulo

> mod(a, n) = a - n * floor(a / n)

> Doing an integer division and then multiplying it again means finding the biggest number smaller than a that is dividable by n without a remainder. Subtracting this from a yields the remainder of the division and by that the modulo."
> source:https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/modulo-of-negative-numbers/

It seemed to help me understand intuitively, and it worked for cases where both a and n where positive and also cases where a was negative while b was positive. For example:

-10 mod 3

-12 is the largest number smaller than -10 divisible by 3. So the remainder is -10-(-12)=2 which is correct.

But when I tried doing 10 mod -3 my answer was incorrect. Because while 9 is the largest number smaller than 10 divisible by -3 it will give the wrong answer as it would evaluate to 10-9=1.

Instead it is supposed to be 10 -((-4)*(-3))=10-12=-2.

But 12 isn't the biggest number smaller than a.

I understand how to solve for the answer using the formula a= (a//n)(n)+(a%n) in python. But is there an intuitive definition to help me understand?

Comment: (a) You say you found “this definition” for modulo, but you do not say where you found it, so we cannot tell you whether that is a good source or examine it to see the context and definitions it uses. (b) For 10/-3, you say “my answer was incorrect.” But you do not tell us either what your answer was or what your Python implementation gave.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil "it will give the wrong answer as it would evaluate to 10-9=1."

Answer (score 0):

The [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) gives the identity `x == (x//y)*y + (x%y)`, from which it can be deduced that `x%y == x - (x//y)*y`. `//` denotes “floor division”; `x//y` is the greatest integer not greater than `x`/`y`.

For `x`=10 and `y=`=−3, `x`/`y` is −3⅓. floor(−3⅓) is −4. Therefore `x//y` is −4. Then `x - (x//y)*y` is 10 − (−4)*−3 = 10−12 = −2.

Here is a graph of `x%3`:
[image]
Here is a graph of `x%-3`:
[image]

Comment: i understand how to use the formula to get the answer. I'm looking for a word definition to intuitively understand it. The previous definition I saw messed up my understanding

Answer (score 0):

I found an anser here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder
it seems there are two types of remainders and a programming languages picks which one to use